# Return new Object that includes filtered nested array

Tags: javascript, list, menu

I basically have a menu system where the user clicks on the store name and it displays information for that store.

That works.

Now, I also have a filter panel where the user can choose to sort the menu list based on the filter button clicked. I can't for the life of me figure this out.

How do I use array functions to create an array that returns a new object that also has updated menus?

```
burgers.forEach(function(e){
    e.menu.filter (el => el.itemPrice < 3).map(el => {
        if(el.itemPrice < 3){
            console.log(el);
        }
    });
})
```

When I log (e) it all burger stores menu item that is less than 5. I want to then create a new object that has all the information from the original but the menu section should be modified to only show the items less than $5.

Object:

```
let burgers = [
    {
    "storeSpace": "Open Space",
    "storeName": "Mcdonalds",
    "menu": [
        {
            "itemImage": "https://www.mcdonalds.com/is/image/content/dam/ca/nfl/web/nutrition/products/header/en/mcdonalds-hamburger.jpg?$Product_Desktop$",
            "itemName": "Hamburger",
            "itemPrice": 2.99,
        },
       {
            "itemImage": "https://www.mcdonalds.com/is/image/content/dam/ca/nfl/web/nutrition/products/header/en/mcdonalds-hamburger.jpg?$Product_Desktop$",
            "itemName": "Hamburger",
            "itemPrice": 3.99,
        },
        {
            "itemImage": "https://www.mcdonalds.com/is/image/content/dam/ca/nfl/web/nutrition/products/header/en/mcdonalds-hamburger.jpg?$Product_Desktop$",
            "itemName": "Hamburger",
            "itemPrice": 6.99,
        },
        ]
    },
]
```

If I call the object again, it does include the items that are less than $5 but it also shows all the other menu items which i don't want. It should only show the first 2 but it returns the whole list of items.

Here is an image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zZE45.png
As you see, that time I set the max amount to $3 and only 1 item in the object is under $3 but it returns the whole menu list. That is why I need to somehow update the current menu item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is code:

```
const newBurgersMenu = burgers.map(function(burger){
    const newMenu = burger.menu.filter(function(item){
    if(item.itemPrice < 5){
        return item 
    }
  })
  return newMenu;
})

// First way to create new burgers
const newBurgersObj = [{...burgers[0], menu:newBurgersMenu[0]}]
// OR Second way to create new burgers
const newBurgers = burgers.slice()
newBurgers[0].menu = newBurgersMenu

console.log({newBurgersObj})
console.log({newBurgers})
```

Is this what you are looking for. Also link to jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/vrheL4tw/1/
Hope I answered your question

Comment: Thanks pal I appreciate it :)